# Instagram API returns "This request requires scope=likes"

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I am using [OAuthApi](https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift) for Instagram login. All my methods are working but for like media post I got an error: `"This request requires scope=likes"`

in my auth init I have:

```
 oauthswift!.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram")!, scope: "likes", state:state, success: {
            credential, response in

}, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
        //println(error.localizedDescription)
})
```

and my media query looks like this:

```
 let url :String = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/MY_MEDIA_ID/likes?access_token=\(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN)"
 oauthswift!.client.post(url, parameters: parameters,
            success: {
                data, response in
 }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println(error)
 })
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `media-id` in the URL where you have hardcoded string `MY_MEDIA_ID`.

I guess you have a typo in the code, so it should look like this:

```
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/\(MY_MEDIA_ID)/likes?access_token=\(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN)"
```

**EDIT:**

According to the [documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/) the URL for **POST** is `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes`, the one you posted is for **GET**. Try calling only **GET**.

Comment: it is not hard coded in my project. I use the same url in instagram api simulator and it works so my url is valid

Comment: Well, sending string *MY_MEDIA_ID* looked rather suspicious, do you have it wrapped around with the **\\( )** just like you're getting MY_ACCESS_TOKEN?

Comment: it is something like that : https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/997274355274462463_88948/likes?access_token=432432432423

Comment: That's valid URL, I'm just trying to point out, that the URL you posted in your question is most likely invalid, because the "MY_MEDIA_ID" is hardcoded and not extracting contents of a variable with name *MY_MEDIA_ID*.

Comment: i didn't write here my real media-id, my url sample works in instagram api simulator so that means, problem is in somewhere else

Comment: Look closely at the URLs of the methods. You are using the URL for GET, but are using POST. If you use POST, put the access token in the parameters and use the shorter URL. That should work.

Comment: my access token is already in my url above. can you write sample valid url with your idea

Comment: I know it is, but it is not supposed to be there. Look in the documentation - it should only be in the URL if you're calling GET method (which you are not - `oauthswift!.client.post`. So instead of calling `post`, call `get` on the client.

Comment: get returns a list of likes, thats not i want, i guess i found the problem here:https://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/

Comment: Well if you haven't filled the form to access the **POST** method, as the documentation states: *To request access to this endpoint, please complete this form.*, then yes, that could be the problem.

Comment: if you find a way to create a sig file in swift, i would appreciate thanks

Comment: No that is not the problem, seriously. Have you filled in this form? https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/185819881608116#_=_

Comment: That's why you keep receiving `"This request requires scope=likes"`. Read closely what I'm trying to tell you and read the documentation. It's the second method on https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/ - URL is `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes`, you need to complete the form to have the access and you have to put the access token in the parameters, **NOT** in the URL.